# how to find count of row in different table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get data from  two different table one table contains total student another table contains specific student information  how i can get the count of student
i want to display `name , code, totalstudent and no.of ngo student`

```
select 
       a.name as name, a.school_code as CODE, 
       a.num_of_student as totalstudent,
       b.COUNT (ngo_student_name) as total_student 
from 
      ngo_student as a 
      INNER JOIN student_details as b on a.name=b.ngo_student_name 
GROUP BY
      b.ngo_student_name
```

this query showing error please guide me 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below- your `count(b.ngo_student_name)` instead of `b.count(ngo_student_name)`
and also other columns in selecttion list should be in `group by` clause

```
select 
       a.name as name, a.school_code as CODE, 
       count(a.num_of_student) as totalstudent,
       COUNT(b.ngo_student_name) as total_student 
from 
      ngo_student as a 
      INNER JOIN student_details as b on a.name=b.ngo_student_name 
GROUP BY
      a.name,a.school_code
```

Comment: Thank for help & how can i find the difference of both column

Comment: just use substraction @AbhinawAnand like column1-column2

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below SQL statement

```
 SELECT A.NAME AS NAME, A.SCHOOL_CODE AS CODE, '' AS TOTALSTUDENT , '' AS [NO.OF NGO STUDENT] FROM NGO_STUDENT
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 '' AS NAME, '' AS CODE, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(NGO_STUDENT_NAME)) FROM NGO_STUDENT) AS TOTALSTUDENT , 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(NGO_STUDENT_NAME)) FROM STUDENT_DETAILS) AS [NO.OF NGO STUDENT]
```